# How to get IsKeyDown method to work in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, input

I can’t figure out how get this method to work:

```
System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.IsKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.Key)
```

The object browser says the following:

> `public static bool IsKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.Key key)`
>   Member of System.Windows.Input.Keyboard
>   **Summary:**
>   Determines whether the specified key is pressed.
>   **Parameters:**
>   key: The specified key.
>   **Return Values:**
>   true if key is in the down state; otherwise, false.

Okay, so it’s a member of Keyboard, right? I used the following code:
Keyboard test = new Keyboard();

But when I type test and then the dot, IsKeyDown is not an option. The only options are from the Windows.Forms members. What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: I think it's because `Keyboard` class works only for console applications.

Comment: Thanks. The how would I get the currently pressed key, even when the form is not active? In other words I need a way to be able to detect key presses even when my program is minimized.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `PresentationCore.dll` assembly as a reference.

Add `WindowsBase.dll` assembly as a reference.

Test code:

```
private void buttonMisc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.IsKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.Key.LeftShift) == true)
        MessageBox.Show("Got it!");
}
```

Comment: So you're detecting a key down when the user is clicking a button with the mouse? :/

Comment: Yep.  I get the message box when I hold the left shift down and click the button with the mouse.

Comment: Thanks so much, Steve Wellens. It worked great. I altered it a little and it works even when the form is minimized. As a matter of fact when I pressed shift for the first letter, the message came up. Thanks again!

Comment: This helped me to detect if Left Shift is held down when a menu item is clicked. The Microsoft help for `IsKeyDown` is incomplete, it mentions that you need assembly PresentationCore (which provides the `Keyboard` class) but fails to mention WindowsBase (which provides the `Key` class with all the key definitions).

Answer (score 4):

IsKeyDown is static, so you need to use it like

```
Keyboard.IsKeyDown()
```

Not with an instantiated object.

You also need to make sure you have the correct using statement at the top:

```
using System.Windows.Input;
```

**EDIT**

On further inspection, Keyboard is a static class... So you can't `Keyboard test = new Keyboard();`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. As I type your code, after pressing the dot, the method does not come up. Do I need to add a special reference aside from PresentationCore?

Comment: @user1739957 You should be able to simply type `Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.A)`

Comment: Nope! Its not an option after I type the dote!

Comment: @user1739957 If you have Keyboard test = new Keyboard, you need to remove that because it won't compile.