# Delete TextBox content when Backspace key is pressed C#

Tags: c#, textbox, backspace

I'm trying to delete the content of a TextBox when the backspace key is pressed, but it is not working. The code:

```
private void txtConteudo_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Back))
        {
            txtConteudo.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

The xaml of the textbox:

```xml
<TextBox x:Name="txtConteudo" Text="0" FontSize="16" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="10,5,16,139" TextChanged="txtConteudo_TextChanged" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984522/how-to-get-iskeydown-method-to-work-in-c-sharp this might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the PreviewKeyDown event instead. Try changing your current code to:

Code:

```
private void txtConteudo_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Back))
    {
        txtConteudo.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtConteudo" Text="0" FontSize="16" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="10,5,16,139" PreviewKeyDown="txtConteudo_PreviewKeyDown" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't use **textchanged event** for that. Instead use **KeyDown event**

```
private void txtConteudo_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyData == Key.Back)
    {
        txtConteudo.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: What namespace are you using KeyDownEventArgs from?

Comment: please see the update by mistake i wrote "KeyDownEventArgs" instead of "KeyEventArgs".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyValue == 8)
            {
                textBox1.Text = "";
            }
        }
```

Comment: I just tested this and unfortunately pressing the Backspace key does not trigger the KeyDown event