# C# KeyDown Event in Game loop

Tags: c#, onkeydown

I'm working on a game in C# and have gotten stuck. So the background is consistently moving, and this is done in a loop wit a Timer to insure that the background moves consistently. Now, I need to check if the user has pressed Spacebar to move the player up. How do I check if there is a keydown event? I can't use a KeyDown event sub because the game loop is consistently working, so the KeyDown event sub won't work. Just looking for some direction here. Thanks!

Comment: What's the `Interval` on `tmrTick` set to?...

Comment: Interval is set to 100 ms

Answer (score 1):

In your tick event you can check for

```
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Space))
{
    ... Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Try capitalized K? Which .Net framework version you are using, this should be available from version 3.0 onwards.

Comment: No Luck with that either. Target .NET Framework is 4.5.2

Comment: Oh, right, that Keyboard class seems to be a part of PresentationCore which is core for WPF... You would need to add references to PresentationCore.dll and WindowsBase.dll see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984522/how-to-get-iskeydown-method-to-work-in-c-sharp for reference

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing as you didn't provided any code.

Try to call `Application.DoEvents();` in every loop and use the `KeyDown` as you intend.

**EDIT:**

OK, this means you are NOT using the game loop, but you have event driven application (usual win application). Call to `Application.DoEvents()` lets the windows to process all callbacks in regular game loop (not your case).

I have updated code again to show how it works - I believe learning by examples is good, but first, you must learn the basics (sorry, but the game is too complicated for learning the C#)...

```
private bool isKeyUpPressed;
private void tmrTick_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    if (isKeyUpPressed)
    {
        // move player up
    }
} 
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs b) { 
    isKeyUpPressed = b.KeyCode == Keys.Up;
}
```

Comment: private void tmrTick_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            

            //backgroung moving...

        }
        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs b)
        {
            //Move player Up
                
        }
The Application.DoEvents(); does not yield any result. Code works without any errors, but doesn't give a result

Comment: What kind of variable will IsKeyPressed be?

Comment: `bool` of course (it is indicated by assigning the result of comparison value). It will be (most probably) the member of the same class where the events are defined.