# C# If more keys are pressed at once how to not stop functions of others?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I know the title was little unclear but i will explain.
My Example:
when i press 'D' my object will move to right,
same for 'A' just move to left,
but when i press 'Space' while holding 'A'/'D',the object will just o the function of the 'Space'.

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            ply.Left -= 3;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
        {
            ply.Left += 3;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space) {
            ply.Top -= 100;
        }
```

Comment: This is most likely a hardware problem.  Low-cost keyboards are physically incapable of reporting multiple key states above a curtain number at once, as dictated by the hardware used. See Keyboard [Rollover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key))

Comment: Without seeing your code it is very difficult to help. If you can add code to demonstrate the problem - then please edit the question - do not add it as a comment as it does not format correctly there.

Comment: @PaulF here is the code,

Comment: What event is this in?

Comment: @BradleyUffner KeyEvent(KeyEventHandler)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove the limit on PC keyboard button presses?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/6669/3047)

Comment: @GSerg if thats the problem then there is no way of fixing it?Instead buying a new keyboard

Comment: @VukUskokovic - do you mean a [KeyPress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx) event?

Comment: @VukUskokovic Correct. Please see the link.

Comment: @ps2goat void Level_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)

Comment: `KeyDown` can only report one key at a time.  If you need more control than that, you have to track keys states trhough both `KeyDown` and `KeyUp`, or use something like [IsKeyDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984522/how-to-get-iskeydown-method-to-work-in-c-sharp) from WPF yes, you can use it in WinForms).

Comment: @BradleyUffner The OP does not expect to observe several keys being down in a single `KeyDown` event. They are expecting a series of `KeyDown` events where each one will execute its own `if`. The problem is that this series never arrives (see the link).

Comment: @GSerg - In a Windows Forms app, only the most recent key pressed will register with the `KeyDown` and `KeyPress` events.  That's what Bradley was saying.  It's not a keyboard issue.  I have a mech keyboard with 104-key rollover, and I experience the same issue with winForms.

Comment: @ps2goat I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Each pressed key is the most recent at the moment when it's pressed (because you cannot read the future and cannot know if there is going to be a more recent key press the next microsecond). If you're saying that it's possible to very quickly press a series of keys and it will only result in one `KeyDown` for the last key, that is most certainly not true.

Comment: I can probably make the if for each combination that can be pressed if that is the only way to fix it without buying a new keyboard,but that will probably duplicate the IF functions.

Comment: @GSerg- If you press and hold `A`, then also push `B`, The `KeyDown` and `KeyPress` event only fires for `B` after you push that key (even though you are pressing both `A` and `B` on the keyboard).  The events do fire for `A`, but only until you press the next key (still holding `A`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can track the state of multiple keys through the use of *both* `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` by use of a `HashSet<Keys>`:

```
private HashSet<Keys> _keys = new HashSet<Keys>();

public void Control_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    _keys.Add(e.KeyCode);
}
public void Control_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    _keys.Remove(e.KeyCode);
}

public bool IsKeyDown(Keys keyCode)
{
    return _keys.Contains(keyCode);
}
```

Now, whenever you want to check to see if a key is down, just do:

```
if(IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
{
    ply.Left -= 3;
}
```

---

Keep in mind that if you just check key states in one of the key events, you will probably have issues with not detecting repeats properly.  If you really want to handle this properly, you should use a `Timer` with a fairly small `Interval` that periodically polls with `IsKeyDown` and handles all your input.

With a `Timer` named `timer1` that has an interval of `100`, you can handle all your input like this, and have *fairly* responsive input to the full range of keys supported by your hardware.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
    {
        ply.Left -= 3;
    }
    if (IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
    {
        ply.Top += 3;
    }
    if (IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
    {
        ply.Left += 3;
    }
    if (IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
    {
        ply.Top -= 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: That solves a different problem from the one the OP has (namely, it allows processing input at arbitrary moments of time as opposed to whenever the keyboard autorepeat fires). But it will not allow the OP to see that A, D and Space are all pressed at the same time, because the keyboard will only report the space.

Comment: it will handle that with `IsKeyDown(Keys.A) && IsKeyDown(Keys.D) && IsKeyDown(Keys.Space)`.  As long as those 3 keys were all pressed and never released, the `HashSet` will contain each of the keys.

Comment: It won't, because there will be no `KeyDown` for some of the conflicting keys.

Comment: As long as their hardware supports full rollover, it will work.

Comment: If the hardware supported that, there would be no problem with the original `KeyPress` approach either.

Comment: Their original code couldn't check for multiple keys, it only ever handled the most recent key press, and never tracked the state of previous ones, this can.

Comment: They never wanted to check for multiple keys (i.e. that was never the problem in question). They have a global object, `ply`, the state of which is changed whenever a key is pressed. That worked fine for them. You're saying your code will let them do it better. That might or might not be true, but even if it does, they did not ask for it. What they did ask is being able to handle the situation when *the user* presses three keys at a time, and your code is no better in this regard (and cannot be, because you cannot solve a hardware problem with software).

Comment: I originally thought it was a hardware issue. After seeing their code, I no longer believe that to be true.  The problem is that they only ever move the object in `KeyDown` by looking at the **last** key that was pressed.  Once they press a different key, the old one isn't counted as being pressed any more.  i've just tested this on a keyboard that I KNOW supports full rollover.  `KeyDown` stops reporting previously held down keys once you press another key.  My code allows you to continue to track all the keys supported by your hardware.

Comment: The issue is that `KeyDown` only repeats the *last* key held down, even if you are holding multiple keys.  It is easy enough to test, just drop `Debug.WriteLine(e.KeyCode);` in to the `Form1_KeyDown` of a brand new WinForms project, hold down "A", then add "D".  You will see that A is reported, then only D.  If you let go of D, nothing is reported at all.

Comment: @BradleyUffner even with your code i cant manage it to work but still thank to everyone who helped me.Much thanks

Comment: To make it fully work, you will need to do your key checking inside a `Timer`, due to the way key repeat stops completely once *any* key is released.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you're trying to solve now. It makes perfect sense, although I believe the OP will be struck by the hardware level anyway.

Comment: @BradleyUffner yea it now work much thanks to you,and for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

As Bradley said, you could save all key events to a keystate cache.

This could look something like this pseudo code:

```
Event KeyDown(e) -> keystate[e.KeyCode] = true
Event KeyUp(e)   -> keystate[e.KeyCode] = false
```

That way, you should always know every state.